# Getting Quota limit while deploying AWS workspace using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create 100 AWS workspaces using terraform. I am able to create the workspaces. But when I am trying to update some properties. The terraform is doing state refresh during that time I am getting quota limit exceeded error

I have tried contacting AWS they said they can't increase the API throttling limit. It is a hard limit. Is there any possible way to limit the number of API calls going during the refresh process

Comment: Please share a snippet of the config managing a workspace for a more concrete example in an answer.